# runtime modeler error while creating very simple web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am beginner in java web-services.

I created a simple web service and when trying to publish it as below

```
 Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb", new HelloWeb());
```

Getting error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class com.ravi.jaxws.SayGreeting is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getClass(RuntimeModeler.java:256)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:567)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:514)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:341)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:227)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:174)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:420)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:439)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:208)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:138)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:90)
at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:170)
at com.ravi.Server.main(Server.java:9)
```

Any Idea whats going wrong here.

My webservice class is very simple and here is code:

```
    @WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use=Use.LITERAL)
public class HelloWeb {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name){
        return "Hello "+name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first invoke the wsgen utility. This utility generates the various  artifacts , i.e. java types needed by the method Endpoint.publish to generate the service's WSDL.Here is the example
In the working directory run

```
  wsgen -keep -cp  package.HelloWeb
```

Comment: From which directory wsgen is to be run?

Comment: I am using eclipse juno and I am trying to use wsgen from classes and src but just getting help from wsgen tool to how to use it

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. But I tried the same thing on Windows environment but it was working without this problem. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: As per documentation, it should work same irrespective if underlying platform. You should ideally always invoke wsgen utility

Comment: I had to run the command `wsgen -keep -cp . package.HelloWeb` in the target/classes/ directory. Thank you for your help.